# Lost all Ruby on Rails syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2 for Windows

Tags: syntax-highlighting, rspec-rails, sublimetext2, railstutorial.org

I'm pretty green at all this and am working my way through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial. I've just started diving into the [Sample_App in chapter 3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top) and just "lost" all syntax highlighting for all files that I'm working on in Sublime Text 2 for Windows.

Syntax highlighting had been working previously, and upon opening the first file of this section in Sublime Text 2, I received the following error message:

> Error loading syntax file "Packages/User/RSpec.tmLanguage": Error
>   parsing plist xml: Failed to open file In file
>   "Packages/User/RSpec.tmLanguage"

Now all syntax highlighting has vanished completely.

I ran some searches, and tried adding this ["syntax_highlighting.py" file](https://gist.github.com/925008/79848555962eaf61847554681d8c5763f730a22b) to my Packages/User directory, but I'm still receiving the same error and still without any syntax highlighting.

Any help steering me in the right direction would be most appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `RSpec.tmLanguage` is not a valid language file that ST recognizes. If you delete that, you will likely get syntax highlighting back.

Comment: Thanks, @MattYork. There was no file "RSpec.tmLanguage" in my Packages/User directory, but I did find the file in my Packages/rails_tutorial_sublime_text (along with another file "RSpec.tmLanguage.cache"). I tried deleting the file from there, but the same error message appeared, and still no syntax highlighting. I then tried copying the file from Packages/rails_tutorial_sublime_text to Packages/User. Now the error message no longer appears (Yay!), but still no syntax highlighting (Boo!).

Answer (score 1):

I have rectified this problem. The `RSPec.tmLanguage` file needed to be moved from `Packages/rails_tutorial_sublime_text` to `Packages/User`. Once that was done, I reactivated my color scheme from the Sublime Text 2 "*Preferences*" menu.

Sometimes the answers are hidden in plain sight, and I actually wouldn't have figured this out without @MattYork, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this error for me as well. If someone is still having issues, here's what I did:

Open `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/syntax_highlighting.py` and remove `User/` from these lines

```
if name[-8:] == "_spec.rb":
  set_syntax(view, "Rspec", "User/RSpec")
elif name == "factories.rb":
  set_syntax(view, "Rspec", "User/RSpec")
```

Restart Sublime couple of times.